# Using dd to change a hex value in Android script

Tags: android, bash, shell, scripting, dd

What I am doing is trying to build a script that can be flashed in a custom android recovery like TWRP or ClockWorkMod.

The beginning:  So using this command at a ADB shell prompt will modify the partition in which the locked or unlocked flag lives for the bootloader on many HTC devices-

```
echo -ne '\x00\x00\x00\x00' | dd of=/dev/block/mmcblk0p3 bs=1 seek=33796
```

I am trying to be able to do the same thing from recovery (Aroma script, but shouldn't matter)

The issue is that while CWM recovery can use these 2 simple lines to complete it:

```
echo -ne "\000\000\000\000" > /tmp/data_new
dd if=/tmp/data_new of=/dev/block/mmcblk0p3 bs=1 seek=33796 conv=notrunc
```

TWRP environment cannot.  The issue seems to be with the quotes and/or the backslashes in the echo.

To get around this I have tried to package a file called data_new with the output of the echo (which is just 4 nul bytes) and then use the DD command, but it doesn't read the data_new correctly because I get 0+0 records in and 0+0 records out.  I have also tried writing a shell script to execute the commands, but same issue in TWRP.

To add a layer of complexity the commands in the aroma script are quoted like this:
    run_program("/sbin/busybox", "dd", "if=/tmp/data_new", "of=/dev/block/mmcblk0p3" etc

I have tried many combinations of single and double quotes and leading backticks but still fails.

Bottom line - **Is there a different way of expressing 4 zeroed out hex values?**

The reverse is not a problem because it's echo to Lock is this: (no backticks and quotes on HTCU don't come into play, since echo output is the same with or without)

```
echo -ne "HTCU" | dd of=/dev/block/mmcblk0p3 bs=1 seek=33796
```

The issue is in getting a DD command to change the HTCU values to 4 zeroes without using backticks in the echo.

Can anyone help?

PS - I think that this could be done by pulling the partition with DD to /tmp and then find the HTCU string (48 54 43 55) and replace with 00 00 00 00, but the partition is large with only a small amount of data actually in it so the process would take a while and the script would be more complicated than I think I could write, as yes I am a noob to coding.
Thanks

EDIT: I tried using /dev/null as that seems like a good idea and a way to avoid echo altogether.  However that fails as well.  Same result as using a preloaded 4 nul byte file.  I know it is not the recovery as the /dev/null method produced the same failure in a ADB shell.

```
0+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes copied
```

Here is the full string of code:

```
run_program("/sbin/busybox", "dd", "if=/dev/null", "of=/dev/block/mmcblk0p3", "bs=1", "count=4", "seek=33796", "conv=notrunc")
```

After dd, what might be the best alternate way to do a quick hex edit?
This is my requirement:
writting into parttion mmcblk0p3 at offset 0x8404. HTCU for unlocked, HTCL for relocked or 0x00000000 for locked
Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you not read directly from `/dev/null` reading 4 bytes; I believe the syntax is:

```
dd if=/dev/null of=/dev/block/mmcblk0p3 bs=1 count=4 seek=33796 conv=notrunc
```

Please double check the above code, I've not used `dd` in a while.

#### Update

After playing around with dd I managed to get it to write 4 null bytes to a position I specified within a file:

Firstly create the example file:

```
$ dd if=/dev/urandom of=randomfile bs=64 count=1
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
64 bytes (64 B) copied, 4.5401e-05 s, 1.4 MB/s
$ od -b randomfile
0000000 105 342 131 116 213 371 352 344 217 236 320 106 010 154 074 375
0000020 360 215 014 203 030 357 144 053 302 265 012 310 217 362 236 303
0000040 156 033 266 035 303 061 262 055 253 102 222 037 372 105 230 321
0000060 117 277 322 277 166 174 316 176 010 202 302 151 120 045 120 334
0000100
```

Then zeroing 4 bytes, skipping the first two bytes:

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=randomfile seek=2 bs=1 count=4 conv=notrunc
4+0 records in
4+0 records out
4 bytes (4 B) copied, 4.4779e-05 s, 89.3 kB/s
$ od -b randomfile
0000000 105 342 000 000 000 000 352 344 217 236 320 106 010 154 074 375
0000020 360 215 014 203 030 357 144 053 302 265 012 310 217 362 236 303
0000040 156 033 266 035 303 061 262 055 253 102 222 037 372 105 230 321
0000060 117 277 322 277 166 174 316 176 010 202 302 151 120 045 120 334
0000100
```

This should extend to your larger file.

Comment: That didn't work.  See edit on the Question Post.  Thanks for the response, it sounded promising.

Comment: That worked when I used the command in ADB shell.  However when I use the command in recovery it reports success and you get almost the same output 4+0 records in 4+0 records out, 4 bytes 'transferred' in adb shell but says 4 bytes 'copied' when used in recovery.  However it doesn't actually change the file when using from recovery.  Odd

Comment: @crushalot strange, are you sure you can write to `/dev/block/mmcblk0p3` in th recovery environment?

Comment: It does seem that in TWRP you can't write to it.  It does work in ClockWorkMod recovery so really a bummer that I can't make a universal package for it as many prefer TWRP, myself included.  Odd thing is that even when I try the updated DD command to a copy of the partition, it doesn't work correctly.  It simply zeroes out the first 4 bytes rather than seek to the correct location in the file.  It's like DD command is ignoring some arguments and that makes wonder if it is just a weird shell environment in TWRP.  Could I copy a more through bash or dd binary over and use that to call it?

Answer (score 0):

**dd if=/dev/null of=/dev/block/mmcblk2p3 bs=1 count=4 seek=33796 conv=notrunc**

This above Ans worked for me... Thanks for the Ans.

**dd if=/dev/null of=/dev/block/mmcblk2p3 bs=1 count=4 seek=33796**

without conv=notrunc argument it used to give
**dd: ftruncate: Invalid argument** error.